# How do command prompt commands work on mapped drives?

Tags: command-line, ssh, mapped-drive

If I am working on my local machine, I can install programs in a specific directory with command prompt:

```
C:\workspace\myProject> npm init
C:\workspace\myProject> npm install gulp
```

I can then run commands from that directory (for example, NPM or Gulp commands) for the project.

How does this work on mapped drives?

If I am in command prompt at...

```
K:\theRemoteServer\myMappedDrive>
```

...and I run the same commands as above, where does the program get installed? I know that mapped drives allow me to read and write to a remote server, but how does this translate when running commands from command prompt on a mapped drive? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What operating system are we talking about?

Comment: I am working on a Windows machine with a mapped drive to a Linux server.

Comment: You should update your question to make that clear.

Comment: The question is about how commands are executed on a mapped drive generally... Where does an install command get executed when accessing a remote drive through mapping? I am trying to understand what happens.

Comment: Still does not change the fact, you should incorperate your comment, into the body of your question.